# including specific RxJS operators

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

lodash CLI allows you to generate a package with specific functions like "throttle".  Can the same thing be done with RxJS?

Here is the lodash example command:

```
lodash include=throttle
```

It generates a 2kb minimized JS file.  Hoping for something similar with RxJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't specific CLI tools to generate those kind of set. RxJS instead recommends import specific operator and let build tools configure it. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-and-treeshaking